# No puedo introducir una fecha desde python a sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Estoy intentando introducir una fecha en la base de datos pero no se introduce.

***printdata.py***

```
now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

data_list = list(zip(maclist, signallist))
conn = sqlite3.connect('db/users.db')
c = conn.cursor()
if (id == 1):
    try:
        c.executemany("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO node1 (MAC,SIGNAL,FECHA) VALUES(?,?,?)", data_list, now)
    except Exception as exc:
        c.executemany("REPLACE INTO node1 (MAC,SIGNAL) VALUES(?,?)", data_list)
```

***table info***

```
cid         name        type        notnull     dflt_value  pk        
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           ID          INTEGER     0                       1         
1           MAC         CHAR(100)   1                       0         
2           SIGNAL      CHAR(100)   1                       0         
3           FECHA       DATETIME    0                       0
```

Comment: Intenta agregar la fecha a `data_list` y pasarlo todo junto a `executemany`.

Comment: Tu primer `insert` no se executa porque `executemany` sólo toma dos parametros, el string sql y una lista de datos. Como tienes un `except` esta parte no te falla. El segundo replace no se por que no te funciona. Tienes definido un default para esta columna? Le hiciste commit a la conexión?

Comment: Se puede saber que error muestra?, para insertar la fecha, lo hago de esta manera. `.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')`